# How to create global object with static methods in v8 engine?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I want to have the same object as `JSON` in my embedded v8. So I can have several static methods and use it like this:

```
MyGlobalObject.methodOne();
MyGlobalObject.methodTwo();
```

I know how to use Function template for the global function but I can not find any example for global object with static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: use `ObjectTemplate`s, just like for the global object you're setting up.

There are several examples of this in V8's [d8 shell](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/main/src/d8/d8.cc). The relevant excerpts are:

```cpp
Local<ObjectTemplate> global_template = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
Local<ObjectTemplate> d8_template = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
Local<ObjectTemplate> file_template = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
file_template->Set(isolate, "read",
                   FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, Shell::ReadFile));
d8_template->Set(isolate, "file", file_template);
global_template->Set(isolate, "d8", d8_template);
Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate, nullptr, global_template);
```

That snippet results in a function `d8.file.read(...)` being available.